Error while migrating. I am deploying my django app+telegram bot to heroku
I am deploying my django app+telegram bot to heroku. While migrating data to heroku, i am getting an error:
C:\Users\Acer\brand_online\brand_online>heroku run python manage.py migrate --app brand-telegram
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ brand-telegram... up, run.7513 (Basic)
python: can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

everything seems simple, but i am not writing /app/ before manage.py.
I dont know where did it come from.
Procfile:
web: gunicorn brand_online.wsgi
worker: python main.py

How to fix?
heroku run python C:\Users\Acer\brand_online\brand_online\manage.py migrate
i tried to use detailed link to manage.py

"i am not writing /app/ before manage.py. I dont know where did it come from"—that's where Heroku puts your application. Is manage.py in the root directory of your project? I suspect not.

SO is for programming questions
